# ConTeXt: Line numbering in two column layout conflicts with marking

Tags: context, two-column, line-numbering, mark

In ConTeXt, line numbering in a two column layout apparently conflicts with the marking mechanism.

As far as I understand (the documentation on this subject being rather scarce), ConTeXt's "marking" mechanism is supposed to work as follows:

After defining a series of markings with `\definemarking[<series>]`, you can mark positions in the text with `\marking[<series>][<label>]`. Each of these marks is the "current" mark for the portion of the text from the mark itself up to the next mark. Now, in the header of the page, you can retrieve the marks by `\getmarking` or `\fetchmark` as follows:

- `\fetchmark[<series>][first]` returns the first mark being defined on the page.
- `\fetchmark[<series>][last]` returns the last mark before the last mark being defined on the page (that is, the last mark that ends to be current on the page).
- `\fetchmark[<series>][top]` returns the mark which is current at the very beginning of the text of the page.
- `\fetchmark[<series>][bottom]` returns the mark which is current at the very end of the text of the page.

So far, this works well, but not always so when using line numbering in a two column layout.

Consider the following example:

```
\setupcolumns[n=2]

\setuplinenumbering
    [
    step=5,
    method=page,
    align=flushright,
    ]

\definemarking[Test]

\setupheadertexts[{\fetchmark[Test][top] -- \fetchmark[Test][bottom]}]

\startbuffer
\dorecurse{12}{words }
\stopbuffer

\starttext
\startcolumns
\startlinenumbering
\marking[Test]{ONE}ONE \dorecurse{12}{\getbuffer}\par
\marking[Test]{TWO}TWO \dorecurse{29}{\getbuffer}\par
\marking[Test]{THREE}THREE \dorecurse{12}{\getbuffer}\par
\stoplinenumbering
\stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

Here marking "THREE" comes to be placed in the third line of the second page. So the current marking at the end of the first page, which is supposed to be returned by `\fetchmark[Test][bottom]`, is marking "TWO". But in the result, the header of the first page reads "ONE -- THREE".

Without linenumbering, the header of the first page reads "ONE -- TWO", as is to be expected.

So how to fix this?

Comment: I asked three times on the mailing list, without real success. I have been pointed to pagecolumns, which indeed gets the references right, but, being experimental, should probably not be relied upon (and which seems to have other issues, e.g. not balancing the columns at the end). So there seems to be no solution.